# GZIP geojson files & Mapbox GL JS

Tags: geojson, mapbox, performance, mapbox-gl

Is there a way to serve mapbox GL  gzipped geojson files?
I have style.json file that pulls multiple geojson files and it is pretty heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you serve gzipped GeoJson files from CloudFront:

1. Make sure the `Content-Type` of the geojson files is `application/javascript` (you can change it in S3)
2. In CloudFront, under behavior, set `Compress Objects Automatically` to `yes`

Make sure you invalidate the folder before checking if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content-Encoding: gzip header on your web server when serving the gzip files. Then the browser will transparently decompress.